# ng-repeat with a filter and dual order by

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of People I need to filter and order by against two criteria. My filter is simple in that if the name contains what they're typing let it through. For grouping, I want to group all of the people with clockedIn=1 first, and then within those two groups I want to order by last name.

My filter is working perfectly but I cannot seem to get orderBy to work at all no matter what I do...

Full jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joshuaohana/82k76uj0/1/, shows all helper functions and whatnot

The repeat I'm trying to setup:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people | filter:nameFilterFn | orderBy: '+person.clockedIn' | orderBy:'-person.userLastName' ">
  <p>{{person.userName}}</p>
  <p>{{person.clockedIn}}</p>
</div>
```

For an ng-repeat, how do I...

1. Filter against a function
2. First sort by a boolean in the ng-repeat
3. Secondly sort against the user's last name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort by multiple field use this syntax:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people | filter:nameFilterFn | orderBy: ['clockedIn', 'userLastName'] ">
```

To use reversed `lastName` use `['clockedIn', '-userLastName']`

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/82k76uj0/2/)

Comment: Awesome thanks, and haha my original had person.clockedIn which is why it wasn't working at all